# Reset element before append

Tags: jquery, html, dom, razor

I dynamically appended model error on DOM using the code below.

```
 $("<span asp-validation-for='" + key + "' class='text-danger'></span>").html(value).remove();

        $("<span asp-validation-for='" + key + "' class='text-danger'></span>").html(value).appendTo($("input#" + key).parent());
```

How do I check and reset before appending?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use attribute equals selector to find element having attribute value `asp-validation-for` equals to key and remove it before appending new element:

```
$(".text-danger[asp-validation-for='" + key + "']").remove()
```

Comment: @uikrosoft : Glad it helps :)

Comment: I would suggest putting an id or class on it to look it up by, rather than an attribute selector.  Attribute selectors require javascript to perform a dom scan of all the elements in the context, as an attribute could be on any of them.  Where as ids and classes are indexed, in some manner, by the browser so they are faster to find. @MilindAnantwar

Comment: @Taplar: Indeed. But the difference is negligible if DOM is lightweight. Updated the answer with class selector

Comment: Still probably a best practice to encourage in others.